# Unity3d - Collision detection and position inaccuracy

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, tetris

I'm a beginner on Unity3D and I decided to create a 3D Tetris to start learning. Everything was fine so far, but I have a problem with collision detection.

https://gyazo.com/49fbf5798dc67a546c5e187fde8f6096

As you can see on this screen, the blue tetromino is not at the good place. This is due to the fact that the orange tetromino position in X is not precise (-2.9999).

Each block that makes up a tetromino has the tag "Block". The ground has the tag "Ground".
This is how I detect collisions in my OnCollisionEnter method.

```
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Block" && !detectedBefore)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < collision.contacts.Length; k++)
        {
            if (Vector3.Angle(collision.contacts[k].normal, validDirection) <= contactThreshold)
            {
                GetComponent<TetrominoMovement>().Snap();
                GetComponent<TetrominoMovement>().enabled = false;
                FindObjectOfType<Tetromino>().GenTetromino();
                detectedBefore = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground" && !detectedBefore)
    {
        GetComponent<TetrominoMovement>().Snap();
        GetComponent<TetrominoMovement>().enabled = false;
        FindObjectOfType<Tetromino>().GenTetromino();
        detectedBefore = true;
    }
```

Do you know how to get around this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's natural to have such inaccuracies when using the physics engine. For tetris it might make sense to do your own grid based collision.

Comment: Maybe you should checkout [c# - Floating-point numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) -> The type `float` only has a certain precision and will almost never reach "exact" values! Also see Unity's [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) where this is also mentioned. E.g. `1.0f != 10.0f / 10.0f` sometimes. When you manually enter e.g. `3.0` into the inspector, internally it might still be saved as the next closest float value .. e.g. `2.99999` or something

Comment: But .. does it actually matter that much? It should make no real difference if an object is "misplaced" about `0.000001` Units

Comment: It makes a difference because a collision is detected due to this misplacement :/

Comment: add a small offset then?